# file not found while executing

Tags: jakarta-ee

```
import java.io.*;

public class NumberOfLine{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Getting line number of a paritcular file example!");
                System.out.println("***************************************************************");
                System.out.println();


        //  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("F://Inputfile.txt");
        //  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        //  System.out.println();
        //  BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        //  String strLine;

            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("F://Inputfile.txt");
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);


//      System.out.println("Please enter file name (location) with extension:");


            String str = bf.readLine();
            File file = new File(str);
            if (file.exists()){
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
                LineNumberReader ln = new LineNumberReader(fr);
                int count = 0;
                while (ln.readLine() != null){
                    count++;
                }
                System.out.println("Total line no: " + count);
                ln.close();
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("File does not exists!");
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No question asked here. What exactly do you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

Your code says to read the file whose path is given as the first line of the InputFile.txt. Is that what you intended? If so, try changing the first line of InputFile.txt to have the absolute path. If that works, try reworking your original path.

Comment: For example, I used "C:\\Users\\Rachel\\Desktop\\Test2.txt" as the first line of my Inputfile.txt and the code correctly displayed the line numbers in Test2.txt.